# Please explain this Java boolean logic statement

Tags: java

```
boolean allValid = true;
for (FormEditText field: allFields) {
    allValid = field.testValidity() && allValid;
}
```

I suppose `allValid` is `true` only if every `field.testValidity` is true, but how is this kind of statement called or how does it work?

Comment: Yuck. Where did you see this?

Comment: After the loop you know if allFields have testValidity() true. I don't know if there is a name for such a code pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by "how is this kind of statement called"? Are you asking for a name? Are you asking when it'll be executed?

Comment: Would be better with an if false statement that sets allValid and uses break.

Comment: certainly this code works. But can be avoided for best practice.

Answer (score 5):

It's a rather cryptic and wasteful way of setting a variable to true if, and only if, all the results of `field.testValidity()` are true.

I prefer something like the following as it's more efficient; unless testValidity() needs to be called on every item in the collection for some reason (in which case the function really ought to be renamed):

```
boolean allValid = true;
for (FormEditText field: allFields) {
    if (!field.testValidity()){
        allValid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks much better. However, this forces me to brag about how nice we have it in Python: `all(field.testValidity() for field in allFields)` :)

Comment: Note this is a completly different semantic. What if testValid() changes some state?

Comment: I believe this is quite well written using the booelan logic. For those who are not used to using boolena logic, it may appear cryptic.

Comment: @johnchen902; absolutely. I mention that in my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I see. Sorry for only scanning for the phrase "side effect" without reading the entire sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. If either expression on the right evaluates to `false`, the `AND` (`&&`) evaluates to `false`, and that result is used in the *next* iteration. Hence any `false` will result in a `false` result.

You might argue you can break out of the loop as soon as you encounter a `false` (provided `testValidity()` has no side effects), but that may actually cloud the functioning of this at the expense of some (perhaps negligible) performance increase. I would prefer clarity over efficiency in most cases

Comment: Is this a common idiom in Java? It looks incredibly wasteful.

Comment: I don't think it is. I'm not sure it's *wasteful* since you'd have to iterate through a collection to determine any false element. Perhaps I would comment it , but I wouldn't be unduly concerned upon encountering it. You might argue you can break out of the loop as soon as you encounter a false, but that may actually cloud the functioning of this at the expense of some (perhaps negligible) performance increase. I would prefer clarity over efficiency in most cases

Comment: Well, no. You could abort the `for` loop as soon as you've reached the first `False` element. That is, unless you're relying on some side effects of `.testValidity()`, in which case this would be even worse...

Comment: I've seen such snippets in some projects. Especially for validation it can be used.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - noted and I've amended my comment (and answer) appropriately

Comment: So instead of  allValid = field.testValidity() && allValid; he could have used  allValid = field.testValidity() && true; right?

Comment: @Ascorbin: No, then only the last element would be considered for the overall result.

Comment: @TimPietzcker There is a hint that the coder indeed wanted to run testValidity() for all objects: The fact that the condition is wirtten as it is and not `allValid && testValidity()` which would prevent method invocation once allValid is false without early exit.

Answer (score 0):

it will turn to `false` if for any `field.testValidity` is `false` because `false AND x = false`

so it has to be `true` for all of them + initial value (which is `true` in this code) to be `true` after the loop

Answer (score 0):

`allValid` will only be `true` if all fields are valid.

`&&` behavior is such that if one of the argument is `false`, the answer will be `false.`

If you have 3 fields, then what is happening is:

```
allValid = field3Valid && (field2Valid && field1Valid);
```

So if any of the fields turn out to be invalid then `allValid` will be `false`.

If field 2 is invalid then:

```
allValid = true && (false && true);  // ---> true && (false) ----> false
```

This is how it works and is inefficient as answer of @Bathsheba points out.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, allValid will remain true as long as field.testValidity() returns true.
As soon as field.testValidity() returns false, allValid will become false and stay false.

This is because false && true = false.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like this code is used to check if all the fields present in the `allFields` variable pass the validation.

In this case, we can modify the code such that if one of the field is not valid then we can `break` the loop.

Comment: No you can't, unless you know that testValidity() is a pure function which doesn't alter state. But since the condition is written `testValid() && allValid` it rather looks that testValid() must run for all array elements for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`for (FormEditText field: allFields)` means foreach `field` in `allFields` check `field.testValidity() AND allValid`. So if in any check `field.testValidity()` returns `false` then `allValid` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the field suggests, *allValid* will be true if and only if all the form fields are valid else it will be false when it exits the loop.  It will be false if atleast one of the form field is not valid.

I think this is intelligently written code and would appear cryptic to those who are not well used to boolean arithmatic. This is how I, too, would write it if I had to but with some comments explaining the intent.